# iOS 8.0 bluetooth peripheral manager giving no callback for addService

Tags: ios8, core-bluetooth

I have created a bluetooth peripheral manager. I  am adding some services to this peripheral manager using [self.peripheralManager addService:myService].

For iOS7.0 I am getting a callback for this method - (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didAddService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error

But for iOS8.0 I am not getting any callback for the same method and I am not able to establish a connection.

Here are the steps that I followed:

1. Create a peripheral manager using
   [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate: self queue:nil options:@{CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @YES}];

2.Create a service using
myService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"AAAA"] primary:YES];

3. Create a characteristic using 
   myCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"BBBB"]  properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
4. Add this characteristic to the service using
   myService.characteristics = characteristic
5. Add this service to the peripheral manager using 
   [peripheralManager addService:myService];
6. The callback for this above step occurs in

   - (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didAddService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error ;
7. In iOS8 we are not receiving this callback.

The code for peripheral manager did update state is shown below.

```
-(void) peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral{
    NSLog(@"Changed State : %d", peripheral.state);
    if (peripheral.state != CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        [self deviceDisconnected];
        return;
    }
}
```

I am adding the service using:

[self.peripheralManager addService:myService];

Is this method deprecated in iOS8.0  or this error might be due to some other reasons?

Comment: Most likely some other reason, but we need more code. There is change between ios7 and ios8 in that ios7 permitted operations before the Bluetooth hardware was initialised (power on state) and issued a warning.  In ios8 it just fails.  Show the code for `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:` and how you call `addService`

Comment: Hey I have added the steps I have followed to start the service in the question description.

Comment: When do you call `addService`?  Inside deviceDisconncted? I.e. After you are in the powered on state?

Comment: I was calling the addService before poweredOn and thats why the bug was coming. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 8):

@Paulw has answered this correctly in the comments. Below is the answer

There is change between ios7 and ios8 in that ios7 permitted operations before the Bluetooth hardware was initialised (power on state) and issued a warning. In ios8 it just fails.

So we must wait for the `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:` callback before adding any service.