# iOS 8 Bluetooth BLE not finding any device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios8, bluetooth-lowenergy

> ```
> - (int) findHMSoftPeripherals:(int)timeout {
>     if ([manager state] != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
>         printf("CoreBluetooth is not correctly initialized !\n");
>         return -1;
>     }
>
>     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(float)timeout target:self
>                                    selector:@selector(scanTimer:) 
>                                    userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
>
>     //[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:serviceUUID]
>                                       options:0]; // start Scanning
>
>     [manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:0];
>     return 0; 
> }
> ```

I control arduino with bluetooth ios app. My app is working well on ios7. So i updated ios 8 not working. I am newbie coder. How i adapt ios8? Here is finding peripherals code.

Comment: Did the library update? Maybe there is another delegate method that handles the located peripherals.

Comment: You need to show more code. The main change between ios7 and iOS8 is that iOS7 gave a warning if you tried doing things before you were in powered on state, iOS8 fails.  What is your `centralManagerDidUpdateState` method?

Comment: @Paulw11 here it is http://pastebin.com/dMgRsENW

Comment: Looks like uuid not available with ios8? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentral_Class/

Comment: You aren't doing anything in `didUpdateState` - It is important that you implement this method to ensure you don't call `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` before you are powered on.  I know that you check the state in `findHMSoftPeripherals`, but do you recall this method if it returns -1?

Comment: You can use `peripheral.identifier.UUIDString`

Comment: [Please check link for ios8 issue ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120834/core-bluetooth-ios-8)