# Are services provided by bluetooth using core bluetooth supported in iOS8?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am using core bluetooth framework for my BLE devices and when I am scanning in iOS8 device, services found from peripherals are "180D" and "180A" but when scanned from iOS7 device, services found was "F4F2B816-A092-466E-BC76-320462D6341A".

What could be reason showing differently in different devices?

For scanning device, the following code was used:

**Code**

```
central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : false])
```

**Code**

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
        if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff
        {
            println("bluetooth is off")
        }
        else if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn
        {
            IBtblScanMenu!.reloadData()
           central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : false])
            println("bluetooth is on")
        }
        else if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unknown
        {
            println("bluetooth is unknown")
        }
        else if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported
        {
            println("bluetooth is unsupported")
        }
    }
 @IBAction func btnScanClicked(sender:UIButton)
    {
        var centralManager:CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        self.centralManager = centralManager
    }
```

**code**

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!)
{
    println(peripheral.services)
    println(peripheral.services.count)
    for service in peripheral.services as [CBService]
    {
        var alert:UIAlertView?
        println("service Id is \(service.UUID)")

        arrServiceID.addObject(service.UUID)
        println(arrServiceID)

        /* Heart Rate Service */
        if service.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("180D"))
        {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service as CBService)
        }
        /* Device Information Service */
        if service.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("180A"))
        {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service as CBService)
        }
        /* Communication with peripheral  */
        if service.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("F4F2B816-A092-466E-BC76-320462D6341A"))
        {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service as CBService)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you check the "services found from peripherals"? Please post the relevant code so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Service id obtained is this "F4F2B816-A092-466E-BC76-320462D6341A". For what kind of service it would be showing?

Comment: Yes, I already know what's the service UUID. But how do you get it? In `peripheral:didDiscoverServices:` method? Please show the code of your `CBPeripheralDelegate`

Comment: @MichałCiuba yes i got in **peripheral:didDiscoverServices:**
I have updated code.

Comment: Please help me to resolve I even don't know about this service.I think this service wont be custom? as it is found during discovering so it will be inbuilt service provided by hardware?

Comment: Yes, the service with "long" 128-bit UUID is a custom one. But all the services (those with 16-bit and 128-bit UUIDS) should be discovered on iOS 7 and iOS 8. What is your peripheral device?

Comment: I am testing on 2 ipod one having iOS 7 is showing this custom service and not able to discover heart rate and device information service.while other ipod having iOS8 is not showing this custom service and that heart rate and device information services are discoverable.What could be reason? is this can be from hardware side?

Comment: But what BLE device do you use? Is it a "real" heart rate monitor? Or you use one of the iPods to act as a BLE peripheral and scan on the other one? If you use iPods as a peripheral, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008296/ios-8-0-bluetooth-peripheral-manager-giving-no-callback-for-addservice

Comment: My BLE device is one hardware device.This link does not help me out as i have started bluetooth then i am scanning so it wont be issue as this link.